# Only play one audio file at a time?

Tags: java, android, loops, audio

How do I make this to play only the sound I selected until I press another ImageButton so they don't sound over each other.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    MediaPlayer leaf,water,fire,wind;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        leaf=MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this,R.raw.forest);
        water=MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this,R.raw.sea);
        fire=MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this,R.raw.fire);
        wind=MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this,R.raw.wind);
    }
    public void playleaf(View view ) {
        leaf.setLooping(true);
        leaf.start();
    }
    public void playwater(View view ) {
        water.setLooping(true);
        water.start();
        water.start();
    }
    public void playfire(View view ) {
        fire.setLooping(true);
        fire.start();
    }
    public void playwind(View view ) {
        wind.setLooping(true);
        wind.start();
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you need to create different instances of `MediaPlayer`? You can create a single instance.

Answer (score 0):

Do something like this.

```
MediaPlayer player;

public void playleaf(View view) {

    stopMedia();
player = new MediaPlayer();

    player.setDataSource(R.raw.leaf);

    player.prepareAsync();

    player.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
            player.setLooping(true);
            player.start();
        }
    });
}

public void playwater(View view) {
    stopMedia();

player = new MediaPlayer();

    player.setDataSource(R.raw.leaf);

    player.prepareAsync();

    player.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
            player.setLooping(true);
            player.start();
        }
    });
}

private void stopMedia() {
    if (player != null) {
        player.release();
        player = null;
    }
}

public void playfire(View view) {
    stopMedia();

player = new MediaPlayer();

    player.setDataSource(R.raw.leaf);

    player.prepareAsync();

    player.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
            player.setLooping(true);
            player.start();
        }
    });
}

public void playwind(View view) {
    stopMedia();

player = new MediaPlayer();

    player.setDataSource(R.raw.leaf);

    player.prepareAsync();

    player.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
            player.setLooping(true);
            player.start();
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: thank you, I get an error in this part (R.raw.laef); error: no suitable method found for setDataSource(int)
method MediaPlayer.setDataSource(String) is not applicabl